# rearrange javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object with depth at most 3:

```
OBJ.T.V.E={...}
```

T and V are integers (like in OBJ[0][1]['String']={...} )
so a typical structure could be:

```
OBJ[0][0]['S1']={..}
OBJ[0][0]['S2']={..}
OBJ[0][1]['S1']={..}
OBJ[0][2]['S1']={..}
```

I want to rearrange and get somehow this:

```
OBJNEW['S1'][0][0]={...}
```

which would have the same value as in `OBJ[0][0]['S1']`

I'm struggling for hours with no luck. Any ideas? Jquery code is also welcome.

**EDIT**:
Right now I tried creating an array of objects like that:

```
OBJ2=[];
$.each(OBJ, function(name, value) {
  $(value).each(OBJ, function(name1, value1) {
    OBJ2[name1]=[];
    $(value1).each(OBJ, function(name2, value2) {
      OBJ2[name1][name2]={};
      OBJ2[name1][name2]['S1']={};
    })
  })
```

But this step fails since each ...['S1'] assignment overwrites the previous object (e.g. S2).

Please ignore any typos, I have just recreated the logic.

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you've already tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: I can think of a magic why of doing it. just iterate the object and replace the values.

Comment: It feels like you're looking for the most complicated way of doing something.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I updated the question with code.

Comment: @frenchie could you suggest an easy way please?

Comment: @sivann: I'm not sure why you'd need to do what you're doing; that's where I'd start looking into alternatives. If your data structures are setup right, you shouldn't need to do those gymnastics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you pretty far, unless I misunderstood.

```
function flipObject(o) {
  var i1, i2, i3, result = {};

  for ( i1 in o ) {
    if ( o.hasOwnProperty(i1) ) {
      for ( i2 in o[i1] ) {
        if ( o[i1].hasOwnProperty(i2) ) {
          for ( i3 in o[i1][i2] ) {
            if ( o[i1][i2].hasOwnProperty(i3) ) {
              if ( !(i3 in result) ) result[i3] = {};
              if ( !(i1 in result[i3]) ) result[i3][i1] = {};
              result[i3][i1][i2] = o[i1][i2][i3];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

It turns

```
{
    "0": {
        "0": {
            "s1": "s1.0.0",
            "s2": "s2.0.0"
        },
        "1": {
            "s1": "s1.0.1",
            "s2": "s2.0.1"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "0": {
            "s1": "s1.1.0",
            "s2": "s2.1.0"
        },
        "1": {
            "s1": "s1.1.1",
            "s2": "s2.1.1"
        }
    }
}
```

into

```
{
    "s1": {
        "0": {
            "0": "s1.0.0",
            "1": "s1.0.1"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "s1.1.0",
            "1": "s1.1.1"
        }
    },
    "s2": {
        "0": {
            "0": "s2.0.0",
            "1": "s2.0.1"
        },
        "1": {
            "0": "s2.1.0",
            "1": "s2.1.1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `hasOwnProperty` solve here?  I seem to have gotten something working without using it (see my answer).

Comment: @Merlyn Unless you *know* that the Object prototype has not been altered, it is unwise to enumerate an object with `for .. in` without checking that the enumerated property actually exists in the given instance. Your solution would fail if, for example, [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) was loaded.

Comment: Good example and good information about why you'd use `hasOwnProperty`.  +1

Comment: @Tomalak, thank you , I also learned that the "in" is not just a for() syntax operator.

Comment: @sivann You *could* use if `( obj[key] )` to check for key existence, but `if (key in obj)` also covers the cases where `obj[key]` exists, but is set to a falsy value like `undefined` or `false` or the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the problem in your original code is that you can't use a plain array `[]` as an associative array `{}`.  String keys can only be used in an associative array.  The next problem is that you can and should iterate over all your string keys instead of trying to hard-code them.

The simplest thing you can do is write `for`/`in` loops for each level of your original object's hierarchy, then flip the assignment when writing them to the new object.  You'll also have to check if the parent keys exist, and if they don't, create them.

```
var NEWOBJ = {};

for (var outerKey in OBJ) {
  for (var innerKey in OBJ[outerKey]) {
    for (var stringKey in OBJ[outerKey][innerKey]) {
      NEWOBJ[stringKey] = NEWOBJ[stringKey] || {};
      NEWOBJ[stringKey][outerKey] = NEWOBJ[stringKey][outerKey] || {};
      NEWOBJ[stringKey][outerKey][innerKey] = OBJ[outerKey][innerKey][stringKey];
    }
  }
}

console.log(NEWOBJ);​
```

As far as I know, jQuery will do little to nothing to help you here.  It really isn't much simpler than the native Javascript that accomplishes the same thing.

Note that this doesn't do a deep copy of the objects you're moving around.  I believe if you change objects in `NEWOBJ` that they'll also be changed in `OBJ`.  I think it would be hard to solve this problem generically, and you'll probably have to resort to custom copy object for each object type.

Also note that I am not a Javascript GURU.  I know there are sometimes problems when iterating over properties in an object that `hasOwnProperty` can solve that might creep up in an example like this.  I don't know what those problems are off the top of my head, though.  For example I tried this code with a simple JSON object and it worked :)

http://jsfiddle.net/e9uST/ - use the Javascript console in your browser to see the output.

Comment: really thank you for your effort, but Tomalak's solution was better suited for my case.

Comment: @sivann: You're welcome.  The answers cover different areas (hence why I'm leaving mine), but I agree that Tomalak's code is a better solution to the problem.

Comment: I think on the right hand you mean = OBJ and not = NEWOBJ (after the inner for)

Comment: @sivann: Nope, that's where you copy the inner-most value from `OBJ` to `NEWOBJ`.  Before that you're just checking if the parent objects exist inside `NEWOBJ`.